# How to read mysql date in format dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: mysql, date-format

I read date from mysql database as:

```
<td height='20' class='datumvijesti'>".$rows['publish_date']."</td>
```

Result is in this format yyyy-mm-dd, but I wont to read in dd.mmm.yyyy. format

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check Mysql [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Example: SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2009-10-04 22:23:00', '%d.%m.%Y');